# Como manipular dados vindo do email

Tags: php

Como pegar os dados que uma pessoa enviou para o meu e-mail de forma automática?

Preciso deste método, pois será um processo seletivo muito disputado e quero pegar os dados que a pessoa enviar para o e-mail e gravar em um **BD** de terceiros, seria perda de tempo e trabalhoso selecionar um por um e gravar lá.

Obs: Pesquisei sobre o **Imap** más não consegui êxito ao tentar usá-lo.

Comment: Esse email vem por um formulário de contanto? os dados que vc se refere estão no corpo do email ou a parte (no caso do form)?

Comment: @rray Os dados estão no corpo do email, basicamente quando você responde uma pessoa por **Gmail** seria isso, quando a pessoa responder eu pegar esses dados que foram respondido para o meu email

Comment: Já deu uma vista de olhos nesta resposta?
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468937/how-to-insert-incoming-e-mail-message-into-mysql-database)